# Error: Failed to execute app and processing manifest.

Tags: android, android-manifest, navigation-drawer

I have created an app in which after logging in user go to navigation drawer        activity but the problem arise when I use **Google Map** in it by using its **API**.Firstly, the app is not showing any error in manifest file when I created it but when I run it it shows some errors which are mentioned below and also show *debug/manifest* file(with errors).

**Manifest File(Before Running):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject">
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.NavigationDrawer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo..API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBWJo_Hlo6ix1927PsMkZJRIvsIz7hrTsM"/>

</application>
```

**Manifest File(After running)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject.activity.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.anasrasheed.MadProject.activity.NavigationDrawer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo..API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBWJo_Hlo6ix1927PsMkZJRIvsIz7hrTsM" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.0" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

**Java File 1(Main)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtEmail;
private Button btnLogout;
private Button btnCnt;

private SQLiteOpenHelper db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    btnCnt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from SQLite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");


    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
    btnCnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Continue();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 * */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
private void Continue(){
    session.setLogin(true);
    Intent int2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NavigationDrawerFragment.class);
    startActivity(int2);
    finish();

}
}
```

**Java File 2(Navigation Drawer)**

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
          fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
        }

        @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer,       container, false);
    }

        @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((NavigationDrawer) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> android:versionCode="1"
> android:versionName="1.0" >
> ```

Remove these two from manifest its already defined in build.gradle file.